# Sqoop failed, error message[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain not found]

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, oozie

I am trying to import mysql table to hdfs using sqoop by creating oozie workflow.

I have copied mysql connector in oozie sharelib i.e. in

```
/user/{username}/share/lib/lib_20150914123648/sqoop/
```

Also i copied my sqoop-import folder which contains job.properties and workflow.xml files.

I can able to execute sample Mapreduce job by referring https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.1.3-incubating/DG_Examples.html

I can able to submit the the job but it shows job is job is  kill with the error

```
 Sqoop failed, error message[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain not found]
```

here is my job.properties file

```
 nameNode=hdfs://localhost:9000
 jobTracker=localhost:8032
 queueName=default
 examplesRoot=sqoop-import

 oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/${examplesRoot}/app/sqoop
```

and this is my workflow.xml file

```
<action name="sqoop-node">
    <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <prepare>
            <delete path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop"/>
            <mkdir path="${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data"/>
        </prepare>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                <value>${queueName}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <command>import --connect  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test --username root --password root --table user --target-dir /user/${wf:user()}/${examplesRoot}/output-data/sqoop -m 1</command>

    </sqoop>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>

<kill name="fail">
    <message>Sqoop failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
</kill>
<end name="end"/>
```

then i am launching the job by issuing the command

```
oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config oozie-import/apps/sqoop/job.properties -run
```

Can Anyone help me to solve the issue.

Comment: add sqoop jar to oozie sharelib folder

Comment: You need to check the `stderr` and `stdout` logs from launcher job for the sqoop action. That will provide you the exact reason for failure.

Comment: @vishnu ->> Already added sqoop jar to sharelib in hdfs and the path is /user/hduser/share/liblib_20150914123648/sqoop.

Comment: you may need to add oozie.use.system.libpath=true in your job.properties

Answer (score 0):

After adding the sqoop jars into the sharelib, don't forget to call

> oozie admin -sharelibupdate

to notify oozie that the sharelib has changed.